# How to create fileuploadfield that maintain previous file selection in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, file-upload, extjs4.2, filefield

There is one fileuploadfield on a form.

What i want : browse and select a different file multiple times but submit all of them at once (on form submit).

What is the problem : On selecting file multiple times, fileuploadfield discards the previous selection and maintains only the current file selection. Thus, on submitting form only last selected file is posted.

Is there any way to allow fileuploadfield to maintain previous file selection on every file select action.

If not, is it possible to create a new instance of fileuploadfield and add it to the extjs form for each file select action (i.e. onFileChange event) of current fileuploadfield.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing one or more files using a file upload control will always overwrite a previous selection. A web page cannot change this browser behavior.

However, it is possible to add files to a queue and free the upload field for new files. For example, [the jQuery MultiFile plug-in](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/) does this.

One ExtJS solution that does this is [extjs-upload-widget](https://github.com/ivan-novakov/extjs-upload-widget).